# i want to get url from iframe

Tags: javascript

this is the code im using.............

i want to get **current** url(href) from below code ...............

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function load() {
            var url =  document.getElementById("iframeid");  

          //get the ifram onload url of href 
    //(i.e)   http://www.image.com/home.html     

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe onload="load()" name="Google"  id="iframeid"  scrolling="auto" style="width:95%;height:600px" src="http://www.image.com" >

    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Beware also of "accessing a cross-origin frame" error.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This will work only if they are in the same domain,protocol and port:

```
document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow.location.href
```

else use :

```
document.getElementById("iframe_id").src
```

Comment: i have undefined result with this code

Comment: `document.getElementById("iframe_id").src` will always return the initial uri.. so not recommended to use it.

Comment: Note: [Changing origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Changing_origin) is possible, but only for subdomain access.

Answer (score 5):

***[The demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/Az9Qw/)***

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function load(frame) {
            console.log(frame.src);
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe onload="load(this)" name="Google"  id="iframeid"  scrolling="auto" style="width:95%;height:600px" src="http://www.image.com" >
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have undefined...alert(console.log(frame.src))

Comment: i have tried alert(frame.src) it given http://www.image.com i want navigation menu urls

Comment: @suryaguruprakash Where is the menu?

Comment: menu in iframe,when iframe is onload ,detect onload and  alert and current url

Comment: @suryaguruprakash Does it have a `id` ?

Comment: @suryaguruprakash Can you point out the where it is in the html source of the frame content?

Comment: it need to work like iframe with Address bar ,so i have only src="web href".if iframe content is navigating at the time address bar link should change

Comment: above the  concept is possible or not ?

Comment: @suryaguruprakash No, not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`document.getElementById("iframeid").src;`

Answer (score 1):

Only two missing bits (marked with <== )

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function load() {
            var url =  document.getElementById("iframeid").src; // <== .src

            //get the ifram onload url of href 
            //(i.e)   http://www.image.com/home.html     

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe onload="load()" name="Google"  id="iframeid"  scrolling="auto" style="width:95%;height:600px" src="http://www.image.com" > // <== Opening angle bracket

    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this. Sometimes you can't acess the Iframe url

```
var CurrentUrl = document.getElementById('MyIFrame').contentWindow. location.href;
```